# Javascript - Get object fields using a given array of keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given this object:

```
const userData = {
  avatar: undefined,
  name: "Raul",
  username: "raulito",
  celebrity: true
}
```

I need to implement a method that receives a list of keys (i.e., ["avatar", "name", "username"]) and get the corresponding values of the userData object, **ignoring undefined values.**

How can I do this using modern javascript syntax?

```
function denormalizeUserData(userData, ...fields) {
  const denormalized = {};

  // For each key (field), get its value from userData, ignoring if undefined
  
  return denormalized;
}
```

So, if I do:

```
 denormalizeUserData(userData, "avatar", "name");
```

The method must return me:

```
{
  name: "Raul,
}
```

Ignoring avatar, as it is undefined.

This is my attempt. I need modern syntax.

```js
const userData = {
  avatar: undefined,
  name: "Raul",
  username: "raulito",
  celebrity: true
}

function denormalizeUserData(userData, ...fields) {
  const denormalized = {};

  fields.forEach((key) => {
    const value = userData[key];

    if(typeof value !== "undefined") {
      denormalized[key] = value;
    } 
  })

  return denormalized;
}

console.log(denormalizeUserData(userData, "celebrity", "name", "avatar"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure  what the issue is. Your code works, and is readable.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function denormalizeUserData(userData, ...fields) {
  const denormalized = {};

  for (const field of fields) {
    if (userData[field] !== undefined) denormalized[field] = userData[field];
  }
  
  return denormalized;
}
```

Edit: in case someone says a code-only answer is blah blah blah

This is simple enough to be a simple code block.

Comment: This could fail if userData[field] is 0

Comment: @Raul Good catch

Answer (score 0):

You can get the object property/value pairs with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), then use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the pairs whose property name is not included in `fields` and whose value is `undefined`, then use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert it back to an object.

```js
const userData = {
  avatar: undefined,
  name: "Raul",
  username: "raulito",
  celebrity: true
}

function denormalizeUserData(userData, ...fields) {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(userData).filter(e => fields.includes(e[0]) && e[1] != undefined))
}

console.log(denormalizeUserData(userData, "avatar", "name"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Grab the [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and build a new object if there is a value, and if the `args` array [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the key.

```js
const userData = {
  avatar: undefined,
  name: "Raul",
  username: "raulito",
  celebrity: true
};

function denormalizeUserData(obj, ...args) {
  const out = {};
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    if (value && args.includes(key)) {
      out[key] = value;
    };
  }
  return out;
}

console.log(denormalizeUserData(userData));
console.log(denormalizeUserData(userData, 'avatar', 'name'));
console.log(denormalizeUserData(userData, 'avatar', 'name', 'celebrity'));
```